# How to insert a specific value after each row that has data in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a specific value in a new row after each row that has data in Excel using a macro. I have found the following script on the net, but this script only inserts a blank row. I need to insert a new row with the value `hello` after each data row.

```
Sub addrowwithvalue()
  m = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  For i = m To 2 Step -1
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.insert
    Next
End Sub
```

Expected output:

```
row1
hello
row2
hello
row3
hello
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try inserting the line `Cells(i, 1).Value = "hello"` immediately before `Next`.

Change `m` to `m + 1` in line 3 for the final "hello".

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub addrowwithvalue()
    m = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For i = m To 2 Step -1
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Next

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
    r.Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```